# Renumber everything that is in a specific column

Tags: unix, awk, sed

1) How would I renumber the second column so that it is numbered 33 through 64 instead of 1 through 32?

2)  How would I renumber the 5th column to add +5 to every number shown? i.e. The first 21 rows would have 6 in the fifth column. The next 10 rows would have 7 in the fifth column.

```
ATOM      1  N   PHE     1    -475.892 131.360  18.903  1.00  0.00      PRT
ATOM      2  HT1 PHE     1    -474.916 131.490  19.239  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM      3  HT2 PHE     1    -476.183 130.447  19.307  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM      4  HT3 PHE     1    -475.832 131.151  17.886  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM      5  CA  PHE     1    -476.789 132.490  19.345  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM      6  HA  PHE     1    -476.569 132.728  20.375  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM      7  CB  PHE     1    -478.274 131.952  19.117  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM      8  HB1 PHE     1    -478.456 131.739  18.042  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM      9  HB2 PHE     1    -478.286 131.075  19.799  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     10  CG  PHE     1    -479.371 132.856  19.681  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     11  CD1 PHE     1    -479.397 133.069  21.055  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     12  HD1 PHE     1    -478.620 132.654  21.679  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     13  CE1 PHE     1    -480.290 133.963  21.694  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     14  HE1 PHE     1    -480.124 134.160  22.743  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     15  CZ  PHE     1    -481.372 134.402  20.921  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     16  HZ  PHE     1    -482.102 134.958  21.489  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     17  CD2 PHE     1    -480.448 133.314  18.973  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     18  HD2 PHE     1    -480.491 132.982  17.947  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     19  CE2 PHE     1    -481.482 134.041  19.531  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     20  HE2 PHE     1    -482.274 134.377  18.879  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     21  C   PHE     1    -476.621 133.775  18.553  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     22  O   PHE     1    -475.878 133.873  17.601  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     23  N   ALA     2    -477.290 134.879  18.946  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     24  HN  ALA     2    -477.881 134.828  19.748  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     25  CA  ALA     2    -477.351 136.159  18.388  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     26  HA  ALA     2    -477.908 136.596  19.203  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     27  CB  ALA     2    -478.334 136.235  17.240  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     28  HB1 ALA     2    -479.283 135.711  17.486  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     29  HB2 ALA     2    -478.622 137.304  17.146  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     30  HB3 ALA     2    -477.977 135.831  16.269  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     31  C   ALA     2    -476.110 136.902  18.239  1.00  0.00      PRT 
ATOM     32  O   ALA     2    -475.529 137.197  19.296  1.00  0.00      PRT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `awk` action:

```
{
    $2 += 32;
    $5 += 5;
    print;
}
```

you may need to adjust the field separator and output format.

Comment: use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html#Format-Modifiers) and width modifiers to format each field